# How to find out which definitions use Temporary symbol?

Tags: core-language

According to the Documentation,

> Symbols with attribute `Temporary` are automatically removed when they
>   are no longer needed.

For example:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Module[{a}, f = a]
Definition[f]
Names["Global`*"]
f =.
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> a$497
>
> f = a$497
>
> {"a", "a$497", "f"}
>
> {"a", "f"}
> ```

One can see that the `Temporary` symbol `a$497` was deleted automatically when the definition for `f` (which contained it) was removed.

**Is is possible to find out which definitions contain given `Temporary` symbol?**

Note that these definitions may be assigned to symbols **in any `Context`**, not necessary `` Global` ``.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach based on documented functionality:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
ClearAll[whereIsIt, isItHere, valuesList, holders];
SetAttributes[{whereIsIt, isItHere, valuesList, holders}, HoldAllComplete];
(* The complete list of known holders *)
holders = {OwnValues, DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, DefaultValues, FormatValues, NValues};
(* The list of values *)
valuesList[ss_Symbol] := Through[holders[Unevaluated@ss]];
(* Assuming that ReadProtected symbols do not lock Temporary Symbols *)
isItHere[ss_Symbol, s_Symbol] := 
  If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Attributes[ss], ReadProtected]], 
   False, ! FreeQ[valuesList[ss], HoldPattern[s], {-1}]];
(* Finding out where the Symbol is locked *)
whereIsIt[s_Symbol] := 
 Cases[{#, 
     ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
      Function[ss, isItHere[ss, s], HoldAllComplete]]} & /@ 
   Names[], {ss_, True} :> ss]
```

The function `whereIsIt` can be used as follows:

```
Module[{t}, d = t]
```

> ```
> t$501
> ```

```
whereIsIt[t$501]
```

> ```
> {"d"}
> ```

The drawback of this solution is that it required the `Symbol` itself and so if one do not switch off history tracking this symbol will be locked in the history as well. Better solution would take only the name of the symbol (a `String`).